# Sound broken: What's using snd_hda_codec_conexant?

Tags: audio, lubuntu

As part of debugging sound that is not working I have hit:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_codec_conexant is in use.
```

While:

```
snd_hda_codec_conexant    20480  0
```

Here are the running processes:

```
$ pstree
systemd─┬─NetworkManager─┬─dhclient
        │                ├─{gdbus}
        │                └─{gmain}
        ├─agetty
        ├─bash
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─polkitd─┬─{gdbus}
        │         └─{gmain}
        ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
        ├─3*[ssh-agent]
        ├─sshd─┬─sshd───sshd───bash───pstree
        │      └─sshd───sshd───bash
        ├─systemd
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-udevd
        └─wpa_supplicant
```

Attempts to reload:

```
$ sound-reload 
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_codec_conexant is in use.
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_codec_generic is in use.
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_codec is in use.
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_core is in use.
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hwdep is in use.
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_pcm is in use.
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_timer is in use.
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd is in use.
modprobe: FATAL: Module soundcore is in use.
snd_hda_codec_conexant    20480  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_codec         118784  2 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_core           69632  3 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                94208  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    69632  6 snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

This is taken from a system where sound has worked earlier.

System: (Almost) newly installed Lubuntu 16.04 32-bit. Sound is known to work, but never tested with Ubuntu 16.04.

**Edit**

I tried `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist snd_hda_codec_conexant
blacklist snd_hda_codec_generic
```

This makes *_conexant not load, but *_generic still loads. When trying to `modprobe -r` it still complains that *_generic is in use.

**Edit 2**

So I dist-upgraded to Lubuntu 18.04 hoping it was a bug fixed in the past 2 years. But no: Same problem exists - even the behaviour when blacklisting.

**Edit 3**

I tried Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit live image. Same issue. Now I will go down and buy a USB sound card. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Sounds like a proc is still holding connections to the kernel module - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448999/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-what-is-using-a-linux-kernel-module. It has to be something... 8-)

Comment: The "0" after `snd_hda_codec_conexant` says that no other kernel module is using it, at least *after* the `sound-reload` script. What happens if you just do `rmmod snd_hda_codec_conexant` as root (sudo)? Any error messages in `dmesg` after boot when the HDA modules and the Codec is loaded the first time?

Comment: @dirkt As you would expect: `$ sudo rmmod snd_hda_codec_conexant
rmmod: ERROR: Module snd_hda_codec_conexant is in use`

Comment: Is pulseaudio running?

Comment: I have tried both having PA running and tried without. As you can see from `pstree` above PA is not running in the example.